# ui.bootstrap datepicker template: access model

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, ui.bootstrap

I'm using AngularJS ui.bootstrap datepicker and I need to have timepicker inside the popup window.
I've modified the template and specifed it in the datepicker-popup-template-url attribute. New template is the copy of the standard one just with  in there and it shows up, but I can't make it usable. When I specify ng-model="ngModel" for the timepicker, it does not change the time in the Date object.
Is it even possible

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to use my scope inside the datepicker template, was by adding a `<div ng-controller="DatePickerCtrl">` in the template, and in my case, making that 'DatePickerCtrl' part of my directive, so I could access the scope.